# Is it possible to disable ssl certificate download in Weblogic server

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, weblogic

It's for personal test. I use weblogic server 12.2.1. I enabled ssl, I can access to my server by https with my web browser, when I do it, it proposes me to donwload the server certificate, all it's ok.

But I want to disable this donwload of certificate, and access to the server only by installing manualy the certificate in my web browser. Is it possible to disable this download function in Weblogic ?

Comment: That is a feature of your web browser and has nothing to do with Weblogic. Without knowing what browser you are using, it's impossible to say if anything can be done.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I use firefox but I it think it doesn't  matter. Yes the browser ask a certificate to weblogic and weblogic "sends" the certificate to the browser. But I want to disable this "sending" in weblogic. I don't know if my question is clear enough ?

Comment: The web server *has to* send the certificate, because it's needed for the SSL encryption. By the time you see any messages, FireFox has already received the certificate, so I don't know what "proposed download" you're getting. If the certificate is unknown/expired/invalid, and I'm assuming that is your issue (e.g. weblogic is using "self-signed" certificate), FireFox will prevent access, but allow you to create a "Security Exception". If you store the exception permanently, FireFox won't ask you again for that webserver/certificate.

Answer (score 1):

Let's get one thing clear, there is no setting in browser that allows user to not to download SSL cert from server and instead provide them directly to browser. And there is not setting in any server that allows user to invoke it's api without providing SSL cert from server to client/browser. Main purpose of SSL/TLS handshake between client/browser and server is to check if the cert of server is valid, makes sure that the server is who it says it is and transfer server's public key to client/browser.

It is a security breach to allow a user to tamper the cert and provide it manually instead of downloading from the server, then there would be no point of green label in the top left of the browser.